# I'd like to make my program re-run the beginning, kind of like a loop javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm making a chopsticks game, and this is my first app I'm making (really new to javascript) and I want it to restart whenever it reaches a certain point until either both the enemy's or your hands have 5 chopsticks.  Here's my code:

```
var nocLeft = 1;
var nocRight = 1;
var handChoice = prompt("You now have " + nocLeft + " chopstick(s) on your left hand, and " + nocRight+ " chopstick(s) on your right hand, which hand do you want to use?").toLowerCase();
if (handChoice === right){
var ehc = prompt("Which hand are you attacking? The enemy's left hand has " + noceLeft + ", and their right hand has " + noceRight + " chopsticks.").toLowerCase();
switch(ehc) {
    case 'right': 
        console.log("You chose the right hand!");

    break;
    case 'left':
        console.log("You chose the right hand!");

    break;
    default:
    console.log("please answer with 'left' or 'right', thanks!");
    }
}

else if (handChoice === left){
var ehc = prompt("Which hand are you attacking? The enemy's left hand has " + noceLeft + ", and their right hand has " + noceRight + " chopsticks.").toLowerCase;
}
else {

}
```

Comment: "loop" is indeed the correct word. Look up "javascript loops", and skip the w3schools links.

Comment: Learn JavaScript. We're not here to make your game for you, just help you with code you can't figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
var exit = false;
while (exit != true) {
  // Your code

  // Use the next line to get out of the loop
  // exit = true;
}
```

The above method will exit the loop after it reaches the end.  If you'd like to exit immediately you can use `break`.

Comment: If you need to finish the loop you'd do this, but it depends on what you're doing.